# problem to run efficentnet code in google colab

Tags: neural-network, google-colaboratory

I want use this code in google colab:

```
!pip install python-utils
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
from .utils import (
    round_filters,
    round_repeats,
    drop_connect,
    get_same_padding_conv2d,
    get_model_params,
    efficientnet_params,
    load_pretrained_weights,
    Swish,
    MemoryEfficientSwish,
    calculate_output_image_size
)
```

but after run this error to me:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 5>()
3 from torch import nn
4 from torch.nn import functional as F
----> 5 from python.utils import (
6     round_filters,
7     round_repeats,

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python'

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.

run efficentnet code on my google colab

Answer (score 0):

it seems that we are compatriots :)

so if you're trying to use the EfficientNet code in Google Colab, you should ensure that you have the necessary files and modules available.

install the required packages:

```
!pip install torch torchvision
```

download the EfficientNet code from the official repository:

```
!git clone https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch
```

and then:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
from EfficientNet-PyTorch.utils import (
    round_filters,
    round_repeats,
    drop_connect,
    get_same_padding_conv2d,
    get_model_params,
    efficientnet_params,
    load_pretrained_weights,
    Swish,
    MemoryEfficientSwish,
    calculate_output_image_size
)
```

just make sure the path to the EfficientNet code is correct, based on the directory structure in your Google Colab environment.